# GoDaddy DNS point my Sub-domain to another Server?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, godaddy, a-record

I want my Root Domain to be still sitting on GoDaddy default IP. (To show the default GoDaddy page that we get whenever we buy a new domain). Then my sub-domains to be pointing to my own WebServer.

- `example.com` ---> GoDaddy Default IP (`e.g, 50.63.202.52`) ---> GoDaddy Default Page
- `dev.example.com` ---> My own WebServer (`e.g, 123.123.123.123`) ---> Development Site

How do i do this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the DNS zone file in your GoDaddy account.

You need to go to the domain listing page, click the domain you want, and then select the DNS zone editor tab.

Then you just add the A records you want.